# Prefixing imports with classes for theming not working

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using Bootswatch and Bootstrap to provide two themes for an Angular application. With one theme that is used all the time, I can do this:

```
@import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/bootswatch";
@import "./assets/custom.scss";
```

My idea to provide users with the option to switch themes was to do this:

```
.yeti {
    @import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/variables";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
    @import "~bootswatch/dist/yeti/bootswatch";
    @import "./assets/custom.scss";
}

.darkly {
    @import "~bootswatch/dist/darkly/variables";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
    @import "~bootswatch/dist/darkly/bootswatch";
    @import "./assets/custom.scss";
}
```

Then I can apply either `yeti` or `darkly` class to the root `html` element, and the respective theme should be applied, and is easy to change by swapping the classes. I'm aware this duplicates the Bootstrap 4 CSS twice, I'm new to SASS so this is the best way I could think of.

This works fine when I build with `ng build --ec`, but when I try to build for prod `ng build --prod`, I get the errors below:

```
WARNING in Unexpected '}' at 7837:43.

WARNING in Unexpected '}' at 15101:43.

WARNING in Invalid property name '.yeti {
        size' at 7820:6. Ignoring.

WARNING in Invalid selector '}
.yeti .navbar' at 7837:43. Ignoring.

WARNING in Invalid property name '.darkly {
        size' at 15084:6. Ignoring.

WARNING in Invalid selector '}
.darkly .bg-primary .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link' at 15101:43. Ignoring.
```

This breaks my navbar significantly, which did not happen when the same SASS built for debug mode. After some digging through bootswatch and bootstrap SASS files, I found that `.bg-primary .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link` is the first rule in the bootswatch `~bootswatch/dist/[theme]/bootswatch` file, which leads me to believe that there is some issue when concatenating the `~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap` and `~bootswatch/dist/[theme]/bootswatch` files with the theme class selector (either `darkly` or `yeti`). Is there a way to fix this error, or "ignore" it the way the debug build does?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I've got the same problem

Comment: @JoeAllen I did find a solution, but I abandoned it because of the large size of the final build. Unfortunately I can't remember how exactly I did it, but I wouldn't recommend the solution I came up with regardless.